# Connection to apache server refused

Tags: android, apache, file-upload

i know that there are similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they did not solve my problem. I want to upload a file from android to a local apache server, but gain a 'connection refused' error.

I'am using a physical device with Android 3.2 and MAMP on Mac OS X Lion (Apache on Port 80). I also added the INTERNET permission to the manifest.

Here is the code:

```
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "/mnt/sdcard/somefile.xml"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        ...
    }

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.x.xxx:80/index.php");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        ...
    }

    try {
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                + SOMEFILE + "" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // create a buffer of maximum size
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1000;
        // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

        // read file and write it into form...
        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

The Exception:

```
07-24 14:48:43.280: E/App(5802): failed to upload file '/mnt/sdcard/somefile.xml' to   
server 'http://192.168.x.xxx:80/index.php'
07-24 14:48:43.280: E/App(5802): java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.x.xxx:80 -   
Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code seems to be ok. The emulator can connect without problems. There was a problem with the router firewall

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the firewall enable and running on your Mac?

The best way (IMHO) to determine whether port 80 really is open is to run NMap (or the gui Zenmap) on another machine on the local network against the target address(es).

If it's just your desktop machine and your Android device, you could try browsing to http://192.168.x.x to see if the Apache server is giving a response.